# gmake repeatedly creates and deletes batch-files before starting to work

Tags: makefile, gnu, gnu-make

I have a C-Project under Windows, which is built with a makefile.
Now I noticed, that after invoking `gmake` it takes like ~40 seconds until anything happens at all (until then there is not Output generated and nothing is happening).

I then used the `-d` flag to find the root of this problem - Running `gmake` with this flag generates the following output in those 40 seconds:

```
Creating temporary batch file C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\make564-1.bat
CreateProcess(C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\make564-1.bat, C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\make564-1.bat,...)
Cleaning up temporary batch file C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Temp\make564-1.bat
```

This operation is happening again and again for the first 40 seconds (same bat-file over and over again).
The bat-file itself contains this:

```
@echo off
dir /b/a-d/-W/s .\*.c .\*.s
```

I don't think that this behaviour is normal (or is it?) - I mean it just creates the same file over and over again - I don't see any meaning in this.
The problem with this is just the time I (unnecessarily lose) with everytime I try to compile it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please provide the version of the tool you're using (in this case, GNU make), as well as the version of Windows and how you built the command for Windows (cygwin, mingw, MSVC, etc.)

`make` definitely never invokes a command like that.  So that means something in your makefile is doing it.  I suggest you look through your makefiles to find the line which contains that command.

My suspicion is that when you find it, it'll be something like this:

```
FOO = $(shell dir /b/a-d/-W/s .\\*.c .\\*.s)
```

This will re-evaluate the right-hand side *every time the variable is used*.  So if you use that variable 20 times, it will run that command 20 times.

Change the `=` to `:=` which will force the command to be run one time, when the variable is defined.

You might also consider using make's built-in `$(wildcard ...)` function, which is much faster and more portable than `dir`.

Comment: Just checked and it is exactly what you were saying. The rest of the issue is "project-specific" but at least I know now what is happening and where I have to look to change something!